# Headers and POST data disappear when using AJAX and mod_rewrite

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, mod-rewrite

I have an instance of Apache 2.2.21 on Windows 7 running at `http://localhost` that uses mod_rewrite to redirect requests beginning with `/backend` to `http://localhost:8080`. The server at `http://localhost:8080` is in turn a CherryPy 3.2.0 server that is designed to accept POSTed JSON messages and respond with JSON messages.

My problem is that when I try to POST to `http://localhost/backend` using AJAX the CherryPy server ends up seeing a message with no request headers and no attached JSON data. It thus returns a 400 BAD REQUEST error. But I also have applications built in Excel and .NET that send similar messages to `http://localhost/backend` with no problems. Also, I've tried setting up a page at `http://localhost/route` (that uses Django) which passes the AJAX POST along to `http://localhost:8080`; this works perfectly.

My question then is why the AJAX POST to `http://localhost/backend' is not working. Perhaps this is related to AJAX security?

Example JavaScript using jQuery would be something like

```
$.post(
    "/backend", 
    JSON.stringify({"type": "getdata", "id": "1"}),
    function(data) {
        alert("Done");
    }
);
```

And the relevant section of the Apache configuration file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/backend http://localhost:8080 [proxy]
```

CherryPy is running with no special startup options:

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 8080})
cherrypy.quickstart(MyServer())
```

Comment: Shouldn't that `[proxy]` be `[P]`?

Comment: I believe [proxy] and [P] are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [mod_proxy and ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)? It's sort of more suited to what it looks like you're trying to do. You'd simply need a directive like this:

```
ProxyPass /backend http://localhost:8080/
```

You can add connection timeouts, retry attempts, rewrite cookie domains, even rewrite response header hostnames with `ProxyPassReverse`.

Comment: I've tried mod_proxy and get the same results as with mod_rewrite. My client applications built in Excel and .NET work fine, but for the AJAX request CherryPy doesn't see any headers on the request nor any body data (the JSON payload).

Answer (score 0):

This actually turned out to just be a case of failing to manually include a header in the AJAX request that specified the Content-Type as application/json. For example,

```
$.ajax({
...,
headers: {"Content-Type": "applicaton/json"},
...
});
```